# zeroclipboard not firing events

Tags: javascript, drupal, zeroclipboard

I am running the following code on a Drupal page

```
(function ($) {

    var client = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("click-to-copy"), {
        moviePath: "http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/zeroclipboard-2.2.0/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf"
});

    client.on("load", function (client) {

        alert("Hello from the load event");

        client.on("complete", function (client, args) {
            client.setText("here is some text");
        });
    });


} (jQuery));
```

But I am not seeing any results.

(1) How can I tell if the `client` object has been constructed correctly? (I know the `moviePath` value is correct.)

(2) When I click the button with id "click-to-copy", I don't see any load event firing (looking in the Console of the Developer Tools window for both Chrome and Firefox.)

Anyone have any ideas how I can go about debugging this??

(Note I wrapped this code in the closure because it originally contained calls to jQuery '$' functions.)

Comment: By the way, is it acceptable for me to cross-post this query to drupal.stackexchange.com or is that considered a breach of etiquette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was looking for the wrong events.

Reading the docs at https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard, particularly the "Static Events" section of `/docs/api/ZeroClipboard.md`, explained that the events I should have been listening for were **ready**, **copy** and **aftercopy**. After making this change I got my code working.